# Intersection of axis-aligned rectangular cuboids (MBR) in one dimension

Tags: algorithm, math, indexing, geometry, time-series

Currently I'm doing benchmarks on time series indexing algorithms. Since most of the time no reference implementations are available, I have to write my own implementations (all in Java). At the moment I am stuck a little at section 6.2 of a paper called [Indexing multi-dimensional time-series with support for multiple distance measures](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=956777) available here in PDF : http://hadjieleftheriou.com/papers/vldbj04-2.pdf

A MBR (minimum bounding rectangle) is basically a rectanglular cubiod with some coordinates and directions. As an example P and Q are two MBRs with P.coord={0,0,0} and P.dir={1,1,3} and Q.coords={0.5,0.5,1} and Q.dir={1,1,1} where the first entries represent the time dimension.

Now I would like to calculate the MINDIST(Q,P) between Q and P :

[image]

However I am not sure how to implement the "intersection of two MBRs in the time dimension" (Dim 1) since I am not sure what the intersection in the time dimension actually means. It is also not clear what h_Q, l_Q, l_P, h_P mean, since this notation is not explained (my guess is they mean something like highest or lowest value of a dimension in the intersection).

I would highly appreciate it, if someone could explain to me how to calculate the intersection of two MBRs in the first dimension and maybe enlighten me with an interpretation of the notation. Thanks!

Comment: To me it looks as if the time intersection is simply the time span when two MBRs' time coordinates overlap as illustrated in Figure 14. So `[max(tP0, tQ0), min(tP1, tQ1)]`, where `tP0 = P.coord[0}` and `tP1 = tP0 + P.dir[0]`. In your example, that would be the time interval `[0.5, 1.0]`.

Comment: If it is just the intersecting time interval, how can I interpret the cross-product sign (I guess x_d is a scalar) in MINDIST (maybe it is just the duration of the time intersection)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Figure 14 in your paper explains the time intersection. And the rectangles are axis-aligned, thus it makes sense to use high and low on each coordinate.

The multiplication sign you see is not a cross product, just a normal multiplication, because on both sides of it you have a scalar, and not vectors.

However I must agree that the discussions on page 14 are rather fuzzy, but they seem to tell us that both types of intersections (complete and partial), when they are have a t subscript, mean the norm of the intersection along the t coordinate.

Thus it seems you could factorize the time intersection to get a formula that would be :

[image: rewritten formula]

It is worth noting that, maybe counter-intuitively, when your objects don't intersect on the time plane, their MINDIST is defined to be 0.

Hence the following pseudo-code ;

```
mindist(P, Q)
{
    if( Q.coord[0] + Q.dir[0] < P.coord[0] ||
        Q.coord[0] > P.coord[0] + P.dir[0] )
            return 0;

    time = min(Q.coord[0] + Q.dir[0], P.coord[0] + P.dir[0]) - max(Q.coord[0], P.coord[0]);

    sum = 0;
    for(d=1; d<D; ++d)
    {
        if( Q.coord[d] + Q.dir[d] < P.coord[d] )
            x = Q.coord[d] + Q.dir[d] - P.coord[d];
        else if( P.coord[d] + P.dir[d] < Q.coord[d] )
            x = P.coord[d] + P.dir[d] - Q.coord[d];
        else
            x = 0;

        sum += x*x;
    }

    return sqrt(time * sum);
}
```

Note the absolute values in the paper are unnecessary since we just checked which values where bigger, and we thus know we only add positive numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, this gave me more confidence in implementing the algorithm. One small remark on the pseudo code: the sum should be squared at the end.

Comment: @JohnWhitmore I forgot the square indeed, but it shouldn't be at the end, rather at each x that you sum. I corrected the pseudo-code.